# nginx rewriting location of permanent rewrites

Tags: nginx, redirect, rewrite

I am trying to redirect from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.com .. However, nginx is rewriting the location-header to $host.

```
server{
    server_name mydomain.de;
    set $root /srv/www/mydomain.de;

    listen 8080;

    root $root;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            rewrite ^(.*) http://www.google.de$1 permanent;
    }

    add_header      Cache-Control   private;
}
server_tokens off;


proxy_buffering on;
proxy_buffer_size 8k;
proxy_buffers 2048 8k;

client_max_body_size 100M;
client_body_buffer_size 100M;
server_names_hash_max_size 1024;
```

That's how my server-configuration looks like. But I am not redirected to google but stuck in a redirection loop. I do have lots of rewrite rules in another server-host (www.mydomain.de), but they seem not being related as this vhost isnt even used.

Error.log reads as follows:

```
2012/10/24 17:26:26 [notice] 2244#0: *175 "^(.*)" matches "/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: mydomain.de, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.de"
2012/10/24 17:26:26 [notice] 2244#0: *175 rewritten redirect: "http://www.google.de/", client: 127.0.0.1, server: mydomain.de, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "mydomain.de"
```

Does anyone know how to solve my problem? I have absolutely no idea what's going wrong.. Thank you.

Edit:
Not even this works:

```
server{
   server_name test.prod-web.hrm;
   listen 8080;

   location / {
           rewrite ^(.*) http://www.google.de$1 permanent;
   }
}
```

Comment: Seems reasonable (except for assigning $root, but that's another problem...) Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: I am assigning $root because I normally include a file called default.conf so I do not have to set some parameters again.. I tried it on different clients with different browsers, always the same problem :/

Comment: You don't have to do that. once you use the `root` directive, whatever you set is automatically assigned to `$document_root` :)

Comment: oh okay, thanks. I tried out a new vhost (see last code block) .. Not even this works.. I tried both the latest stable and development release of nginx..

Comment: Okay, I finally solved the problem. I use POUND in front of my backend systems as a ssl-proxy. And pound is obviously automatically rewriting every location headers it receives by default. I disabled it (RewriteLocation 0) and now it works. Thank you all for you help! I can't self-answer my question now so I'm adding the solution as a comment.

Comment: Yep, you should have mentioned that. Feel free to accept any answer you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use `rewrite` for this at all.

Instead, try this:

```
return 301 $scheme://www.example.com$request_uri$is_args$args;
```

If this fails, you probably have something else in your environment causing the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it out, but I am still stuck in a redirection loop.. Not even an entry in the error.log (debug-mode).. My client just receives "Location: http://test.prod-web.hrm" (same host as my vhost), but nginx config says return 301 http://www.google.de

Comment: You have something else going on, then. Look at the rest of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an additional server for the rewrite:

```
   server {
      listen       192.168.1.234:80;
      server_name  example.com;                # your domain name

      rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
   }
```

That really should be it.  Mind the forward slash you lack

Comment: So no location stuff, just this.... check the [nginx pitfalls page](http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls), I don't understand why you would set a $root var.